Suspension spectrum functor
Let $\operatorname{Sp}$ be the $\infty$-category of spectra, and $S_*$ be the $\infty$-category of pointed spaces. We know that there is the suspension spectrum functor $\Sigma^{\infty}: S_* \to \text{Sp}$ as the left adjoint of the loop functor $\Omega^{\infty}$. What exactly is the $n$-th space of $\Sigma^{\infty}X$ for a given pointed space $X$? In fact, some sources say it is $\Sigma ^{n} X \simeq S^n \wedge X$. And, some others define it by $Q\Sigma^n X$, where $QX:= \operatorname{colim}\Omega^m \Sigma^mX$. I am a little bit confused between these two definitions. are they equivalent?

I have not seen the latter definition, but my presumption is this has more to do with the question of "what is a spectrum?" than "what is the suspension spectrum?"  i.e. which version of spectra one chooses to be compliant with.

Hi Ryan. It's been defined in Nardin's notes in the statement right before lemma 2.9.

The second version is making an $\Omega$-spectrum. The colimit forces the adjoints of the structure maps to become equivalences.

The sequence of spaces $E_n := \Sigma^nX$ forms what is called a pre-spectrum, that is, there are maps $\Sigma E_n \to E_{n+1}$ or equivalently $E_n\to \Omega E_{n+1}$, but it is not a spectrum/$\Omega$-spectrum.
The other object, $F_n := colim_m \Omega^m\Sigma^{m+n}X$ is a spectrum, and it is the so-called spectrification of the pre-spectrum above. This "is" $\Sigma^\infty X$, and the former is a "precursor" to it - though the fact that $\Sigma^\infty X$ is the spectrification of this simple pre-spectrum is the reason for its name "infinite suspension".
In model category language, pre-spectra also form a model for the $\infty$-category of spectra, but the weak equivalences one has to consider essentially involve spectrification ! From an $\infty$-categorical perspective, there is an $\infty$-category $PreSp$ of pre-spectra, inside which there is a full subcategory $Sp$ of spectra, and the inclusion $i: Sp \to PreSp$ has a left adjoint, "spectrification".
However, while in model category theory pre-spectra can be technically convenient, $\infty$-categorically they are much less relevant (though not completely irrelevant), and so they are much less discussed - in particular the description of $\Sigma^\infty X$ as a pre-spectrum from earlier is much less popular and you may not encounter it so much.
